# Make only author in bibliography bold (year should not be bold)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

i want in my bibliography the author bold and year shoud be normal. Like the example: [image]

and not like this :[image]

Here the part of the sourcecode of my preamble file:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber, style=authoryear, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{18pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0.2cm}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
 andothers = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
 andmore = {et\addspace al\adddotspace},%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}
```

Comment: Please prepare a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (see also [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)). With just a few bits of code it can be hard to give an answer that really works for you. Do you want all authors bold or just specific ones?

Comment: i want all authors bold but the year should not be bold

Comment: OK, could you show us a complete example (as explained in the links in my first comment), so we can get started from the right assumptions.

Comment: With modern `biblatex` you want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` instead of `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

For easy author bolding in the bibliography, just use

```
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

No need for `xpatch` and friends.

---

### Old answer

Use

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\def\bmkbibbold#1\emkbibbold{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\bmkbibbold}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
  {\emkbibbold\usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
  {}{}

\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\bmkbibbold}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
  {\emkbibbold\usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
  {}{}

\xpretobibmacro{bbx:translator}{\bmkbibbold}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
  {\emkbibbold\usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
  {}{}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

This will exempt the year from bolding and will also do the right thing for translators. The macro with delimited argument might be a bit risky, so in general a solution that properly uses grouping should be preferred. Unfortunately, `biblatex`'s font commands are all macros and not switches.